# Dataframe is not being updated with values; output is a warning 'copy of a slide'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames with the following values:

**df1**

```
               Cash
Date               
2011-01-10 -5114.85
2011-01-11 -5000.85
```

**df2**

```
              GOOG    AAPL     XOM     IBM        Cash  
2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     -19.900 
2011-01-11     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0       0.000
```

For every entry in df1, I check if that index exists in df2. If the index exists then I want to add value from df1 with df2 into df2; updating the value in df2 for the same say it exists in df1.

I'm trying to achieve that with the following code:

```
for each in df1.index:
    if each in df2.index:
        df2.loc[each]['Cash'] = df1.loc[each]['Cash'] + df2.loc[each]['Cash']
```

The output in the console is:

*SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df2.loc[each]['Cash'] = df1.loc[each]['Cash'] + df2.loc[each]['Cash']*

I assume a warning will still let me execute the code and update my column values in df2...

**Error**

trades data frame is not being populated with the updated value.

**Expected Output**

```
              GOOG    AAPL     XOM     IBM        Cash  
2011-01-10     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     -5134.75 
2011-01-11     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     -5000.85
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df.index.intersection` to find common indexes, and then use `loc` to access all relevant rows and add.

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
df2.loc[idx, 'Cash'] += df1.loc[idx, 'Cash']

print(df2)
            GOOG  AAPL  XOM  IBM     Cash
2011-01-10   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0 -5134.75
2011-01-11   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0 -5000.85
```

Comment: I apologize; what I want is that if two indices matches, add cash from df1 into df2. Like; -5114.85+-19.9 = -5134.75

Thanks. I have updated my output :(.

Comment: @Codinghierarchy Lucky for you the second method requires almost no modification to work for your case. See edit.